# Why fontawesome icon does not show up? at Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Why fontawesome icon does not show up? at Chrome and Safari?

Bootstrap and Fontawesome on Chrome and Safari.
They do not show anything.
Here is my code. Feel stupid struggling with this super easy task...

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It should work but why it is not showing anything? Can anyone help me?

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://github.com/" target="blank">GitHub</a>
    <i class="icon-github-alt"></i>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work's ok for me - see sample below:

http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/tmWVz/

Why are you loading the

```
bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css
```

file?

You only need

```
bootstrap.min.css
font-awesome.min.css
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try including it this way. If you are working local and not on a browser trys to fetch the files from your hard drive.

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It's important not to forget the **http:** when working local.